# What's Blanking time in Flyback

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control, flyback

I read some documents (see below) about the blanking time of flyback. Both are talking about it, but I don't know exactly what this function does. I also tried to get an explanation from the datasheet, but still confused about it. Why this is so important?

From [Infineon design guide](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Design_guide_converter_design_using_QR_PWM_controller_ICE2QS02G-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30431a5c32f2011ac41304793852):

[image]

From [onsemi datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1342-d.pdf):

[image]

Comment: The name may be the same but they serve different functions, which are explained in the datasheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be adequately explained in the datasheet you linked (emphasis added):

> BL (Adjustable Blanking Time)
> By connecting a capacitor and a resistor in parallel between this pin and the ground, the blanking time for can
> be fully adjusted, as well as the restart time. **This allows the system to face a sudden power surge for a short
> period of time without triggering the overload protection. Once the protection triggered, the IC will restart
> using the internal soft-start circuit, after a period of time fixed by the external resistance and capacitor.**

Blanking allows a short overload, after which the converter will shut off and then try again after a delay. This kind of function is sometimes called "shutdown and retry".

Comment: More generally, blanking time is a word for a time period in which some event is ignored, where the device would normally respond to that event in some way. Switching regulators with protection systems usually have blanking time on those, to ensure that a momentary, expected, non-fault event (like inrush current or ringing) doesn't cause nuisance trips of the protection circuitry.

Comment: Hi Hearth and Spehro,

I can understand more clear now. 
do you know how to do the blank time in analog circuit?

Comment: @Jitter456  Assuming you mean without using that chip, you could just use a monostable logic chip. R and C will set the blanking time.

Comment: I got it, thanks.